# UnBadging the app icon (Swift)

Tags: ios, notifications, icons, uilocalnotification, cancellation

My notifications work and the app icon is badged it shows up in the notification center as well but when go into the app or clear notifications.

In the notification center my app icons badge number remains the same
code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) 
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you should set the badge number to non-zero value, then set it to zero. the last code is to clear notification in the notification center.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: Please answer in swift @jinhua liao